# What is the complexity of this approach to finding K largest of N numbers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In [this post on how to find the K largest of N elements](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/) the 2nd method proposed is:

1. Store the first k elements in a temporary array temp[0..k-1].
2. Find the smallest element in temp[], let the smallest element be min.
3. For each element x in arr[k] to arr[n-1]
   If x is greater than the min then remove min from temp[] and insert x.
4. Print final k elements of temp[]

While I understand the approach, I do not understand their computed
Time Complexity of  `O((n-k)*k)`.

From my perspective, you are making a linear traversal of `n-k` elements and doing a single comparison on each element. And then perhaps replacing one elements of the temporary array of `K` elements.

More specifically, where does the `*k` aspect of their computed
Time Complexity of  `O((n-k)*k)` come from? Why do they multipy `n-k` by that?

Comment: Perhaps because you have to compare each element of the temp array (k) with each remaining element of the initial array (n - k), that is k * (n - k). It appears that the algorithm description is a little bit wrong, since you have to repeat steps #2 and #3 if I am not mistaken :)

Comment: Use max-heap to store the numbers, the total complexity then will be `O(n)` for build-heap and `O(k*lg(n))` to find k-largest elements.

Comment: @SandipanDey or better yet build min-heap for first _k_ elements and then do _(n-k)_ insertions and delete-mins for _(n-k)logk_ time then do _k_ find-mins and delete-mins for another _klogk_ for a total of _nlogk_ time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider that at `kth iteration` :

```
arr[k] > min(temp[0..k-1]
```

Now you will replace `min(temp[0..k-1])` with `arr[k]`.

And now you again need to compute the updated `min` of `temp[0..k-1],` because that would have changed. It can be any number in your updated `temp[0..k-1]`

So in worst case, u update the min everytime and hence the `O(k)`.

Thus, **time complexity** = `O((n-k)*k)`